# Mysql query to get the value

Tags: mysql

I got the table structure as follows

```
--------------------------------
id   processId   newId     value
--------------------------------
1        1        1         a
2        1        2         b
3        1        4         c
4        2        5         d
--------------------------------
```

and

```
------------------------
id   processId  mapnewId
------------------------
1        1        1
2        1        2
------------------------
```

How should i get the value "**c**" (that means i should get the value which is not mapped to "**1**" in the second table) from the table in which the id mapped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the answer for single record

```
Select 
    t1.processId,
    t1.newId,
    t1.value,
    t2.processId,
    t2.mapnewId
FROM  t1
LEFT JOIN t2 
ON t1.processId = t2.processId and t1.newId =  t2.mapnewId
where t1.processId = 1 and t2.processId is null
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the my understanding you are looking for some query which will return the rows which are not der in second table..
If that's fine, then "Except" operation will help you out with the same :

The SQL EXCEPT clause/operator is used to combine two SELECT statements and returns rows from the first SELECT statement that are not returned by the second SELECT statement. This means EXCEPT returns only rows which are not available in second SELECT statement.

Please refer:  http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-except-clause.htm

Comment: `EXCEPT` could help here. Except that it isn't supported in MySQL.